# jQuery catch img

Tags: jquery

We have a script used for each `.item`:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    item_link = "http://...";
    block = $('.block', this);
    $.get(item_link, function(data) {
        var src = $('img.slide', data).attr('src');
        block.html(src);
    });
});
```

`item_link` variable is uniquie for each query.

There can be 100 `.item` or more.

The problem is - server has limit on connections at the same time, that why some `.item` get `var src`, some not.

The best solution is to use just one `.get` at the same time. I think there should be some counter, if `.get` is finished - it gives message "**I'm finished, you can start**" to the next `.get` and so on.

**How to do that?**

Thanks.

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>The browser should automatically queue the requests and send each one after one of the previous two finish.</strike>

Therefore, your current code should work fine.
Check Fiddler or Firebug and see whether the requests are failing.

## EDIT

You're fighting a server throttle, not the browser's connection limit.

You need to maintain an array of functions that send requests, then call the next function in the AJAX callback.

For example:

```
var requests = [];
function runFirstRequest() {
    if (requests.length > 0)
        requests.splice(0, 1)();  //Pop the first function from the queue and execute it
}


$(".item").each(function(){
    item_link = "http://...";
    block = $('.block', this);

    requests.push(function() {
        $.get(item_link, function(data) {
            var src = $('img.slide', data).attr('src');
            block.html(src);

            runFirstRequest();    //Send the next request
        });
    });
});

runFirstRequest();
```

---

However, sending hundreds of AJAX request is a bad idea.
You should modify your code to send a single AJAX request that returns all of the data you need.
This will solve your problem and make the page much faster.

Comment: there are a lot of GET requests, much of them give "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Comment: I highly recommend that you try to change your system to allow you to combine the requests.  (Using server-side code)

Comment: You should debug the code and figure out what's wrong.  If you need help, please show us your exact code.

Comment: You forgot to call `runFirstRequest();` after filling the queue.

Answer (score 2):

you should just put them all in one big request and let the server loop through them instead:

```
items_ids = [];
$(".item").each(function(){
    item_ids.push( some_identifier_for_the_item );
});

get_item_data_link = "http://...";
$.get(item_link, {"items": item_ids}, function(data) {
    ... loop through the results and stick them in the page
});
```

PS - if you're still set on making a request queue use push, pop, shift and unshift

First in first out queue:

```
queue = [];

// add 3 items to the queue
queue.push('item1');
queue.push('item2');
queue.push('item3');

// get the oldest item off the queue (ie. the first item
// added is the first item handled)

queue.shift(); // "item1"
```

Last in, first out queue:

```
queue = [];

// add 3 items to the queue
queue.push('item1');
queue.push('item2');
queue.push('item3');

// get the newest item off the queue (ie. the last item
// added is the first item handled)

queue.pop(); // "item3"
```